# [ExtendScript]Change font color, size of certain word in text layer

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I want replace font color and weight and size of certain word in text layer.
For example:

```
I want <b>THIS</b> look different
 and <b>this</b> as well.
```

My plan was replacing every characters' color between <b> and </b> then "<b>" and "</b>" to be removed.

First of all, I'd like to know that changing colors and size of certain words in a text layer would even be feasible.

Another thing is, even if I somehow manage to change font color in a text layer and then remove <b> and </b>, font colors change back to what it was before. To the color of first character of the layer.

```
function Replace132Step1(){
    var desctxt  = app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName ("Description");
    var reg = new RegExp("(<b>.*<\/?b>)");
    var boldColor1 = new SolidColor();
    boldColor1.rgb.hexValue= 'EE3E2E';
    //I got stuck from here. .replace doesn't seem like to work.

}

function Replace132Step2(){
    var desctxt  = app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName ("Description");
    desctxt.textItem.contents = desctxt.textItem.contents.replace("<b>", "");
    desctxt.textItem.contents = desctxt.textItem.contents.replace("</b>", "");    
}
```

Comment: Sorry, It wasn't about CSS nor HTML.

Comment: If it's not possible to change it within a single text layer, have you thought about splitting the text layer (as in example) by the tags? 1. Explode "Description" layer by line breaks 2. Explode lines by tags, 3. Create "I want " layer (get its size to measure where to put next layer), create "THIS " layer and attach bold style, create "look different" layer (again, basing on previous layers' sizes). 4. Repeat for subsequent lines.